# What's the most clean and pythonic way to load data from one of two file paths? Why can't I catch two of the same Exceptions?

Tags: python, file, exception, error-handling

I have two potential file-paths where my application can read specific data from. If one fails, I want it to read from the other.

My intuitive attempt to do so was with try...except clauses, having something as below:

```py
# Try the first file path
try:
    file = open(possible_path_1)
    content = file.read()

# File is not in first location, try the second
except IOError:
    file = open(possible_path_2)
    content = file.read()

# Could not read from either location, throw custom CriticalException
except IOError:
    raise CriticalException("Could not read the file!")
```

However, this does not seem to work as intuitively expected. The second IOError is never caught. Why is this the case? Is there any "clean" way to read from one file path or the other without having to manually check `os.path.exists(filepath) and os.path.isfile(filepath)`?

Comment: because you need to wrap what's inside the first `except` clause in *another* try-except, this one nested in there. not a third clause

Comment: I am aware I can do this, but it's just too darn ugly. I am refusing to do that and wondering if there's a cleaner alternative. Maybe I'm asking for Utopian code...

Comment: ok have fun with that. you are basically asking for an `if-elif-else` construct except with exception handling

Comment: Why not iterate over the paths, such as `for path in possible_paths: try:...`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Might just end up doing that, and adding a `break` if the file is read properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative, but not sure if it is "prettier":

```
for path in paths:
    try:
        file = open(path)
        content = file.read()
    # File is not in first location, try the second
    except IOError:
        continue
    break
else: # for-else gets executed if break never happens
    raise CriticalException("Could not read the file!")
```

Assuming you have all your possible paths in some container, `paths`

Although honestly, I simply wouldn't use exception handling here, I think this is much clearer (and of course, I would use `pathlib` not `os.path`:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in map(Path, paths):
    if path.exists():
        content = path.read_text()
        break
else:
    raise CriticalException("Could not read the file!")
```

Comment: I like this much better. That `else` statement after the `for`... Never know about that. Cheers mate!

Comment: Shouldn't the break be within the `if path.exists()` clause?

Comment: @Dalofeco yep, typo